# Laravel Auth Reset Password Function View doesnt work

Tags: laravel, authentication

I made this:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Everything works, so I can register a user and can login.

If I click on Forget Password, it redirected me to /password/reset, but it shows me an empty page?

I don't know why because I have all the files, but I don't know what happens here.

Where can I see the auth routes?

In my web.php, I only make this:

```
Auth::routes();
```

I am using Laravel 5.6.

if i do

```
php artisan route:list
```

these are my auth routes

```
     |
|        | POST      | login                             |                    |
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                             | login              |
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest      |
|        | POST      | logout                            | logout             |
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web
        |
|        | POST      | password/email                    | password.email     |
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest      |
|        | POST      | password/reset                    |                    |
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset                    | password.request   |
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}            | password.reset     |
        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                          | register           |
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest      |
|        | POST      | register                          |                    |
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register             web,guest      |
        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | user/verify/{token}               |                    |
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@verifyUser                | web,auth,guest |
```

so i have all my reset routes

but i see in my env i do not have any passwords/reset

this is my env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel

APP_ENV=local

APP_KEY=base64:KAZ1F3lzqe6oG3XkXT06ZQ6MYoQZibd7vaHDLCq8CvY=
APP_DEBUG=true

APP_URL=http://localhost


LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=j4y

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log

CACHE_DRIVER=file

SESSION_DRIVER=file

SESSION_LIFETIME=120

QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_PASSWORD=null

REDIS_PORT=6379   

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io

MAIL_PORT=2525

MAIL_USERNAME=b3f31fa6ba1f07
MAIL_PASSWORD=635d101e8896d8
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null    

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=

PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"

MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

how have it look like?

and this is my view file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Passwort vergessen</title>
</head>
<body>
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
@if (session('warning'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        {{ session('warning') }}
    </div>
@endif

@include('layouts.app')
@include('partials.userhead')
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Reset Password') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Reset Password') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">


                       <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ $email ?? old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>
                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Reset Password') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    @include('partials.footer')
```

Comment: php artisan routes:list will show you the list of all routes

Comment: Did you change any of the auth views? Do you have them all?

Comment: Is debugging on in the `.env` file? How does your view file look for `/password/reset`?

Comment: so the routes are all right but i think it is becuase my .env i updated my post, so dwhats the problem here?

Comment: i can not find this file :Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails; is this the problem?? i am in the folder but there is no file likethat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont have this in my app.blade.php because i modify this file

```
<main class="content">
    @yield('content')
</main>
```

but now it works